# Do GitHub invitations expire?

Tags: github

I was invited to join a repository but now the link in the email doesn't work anymore.

Do GitHub invitations on a repository expire, and if so, how long do they last?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitHub invitations expire after seven days, so if you don't accept the invitation within then, an admin of the repository will have to resend the invitation.

> Pending invitations will expire after 7 days

[Source](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-access-to-your-personal-repositories/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository)

Comment: Same answer can be found here: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-02-05-self-expiring-repository-and-organization-invitations/

"Invitations to join an organization or become a collaborator on a repository will expire seven days after they are created."

Apparently this expiry was introduced in 2020.